# Install apk from external storage from another application without confirmation activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, apk

This is example of code which install apk file from external storage with confirmation activity:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/app-debug.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);
```

I need install apk from external storage without confirmation activity.
Is it possible?

Comment: If your device is "rooted", it's possible, then I'll give you the code. If not, then it's not possible.

Comment: without root is not possible. That's Why Amazon and Mikandi "app stores" asks for the user confirmation.

Comment: this is specific device I do customization of android for this device.

Comment: I can use ndk, sdk or lowest level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem.
In order to install apk from any storage we can use PackageManager and hidden api.
This is example of code:

```
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    Uri packageURI = Uri.fromFile(new File(pathToApkFile));
    manager.installPackage(packageURI, null, 2, "app");
```

installPackage it is hidden api and you need build your app in aosp

Answer (score 0):

On a rooted device you can use this code which reverts to asking the confirmation on a non-rooted device too. This auto-updates the actually running application and restarts it.

```
// path is the complete path to the APK file, startActivityName is the name of the activity to start once the install is complete.
private boolean rootUpdateAPK(String path, String startActivityName)
{       
    final String libs = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib ";
    final String[] commands = {
            libs + "pm install -r " + path,
            //              libs + "reboot"
            //      };
            libs + "am start -n " +  this.getPackageName() + "/."+startActivityName
    };
    execute_as_root(commands);  // not supposed to return if successful

    // device is not rooted, let's do it the "regular" way.

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);

    return false;
}

private void execute_as_root( String[] commands ) {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "su" );
        InputStream es = p.getErrorStream();
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());

        for( String command : commands ) {
            TVLog.i(TAG,"Execute as root: "+command);
            os.writeBytes(command + "\n");
        }
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        String output = new String();
        while ((read = es.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output += new String(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        p.waitFor();
        TVLog.i(TAG, output.trim() + " (" + p.exitValue() + ")");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        TVLog.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        TVLog.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me.
I need install application from apk without confirmation and root.

Comment: You can't, or you must make your application a system app and make it part of the firmware since you don't want to or can root.

Comment: my app is a system app